# Show that $f(\vec{x})$ is constant on a sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

Can someone please explain what they're doing here? I'm so confused as to what the question is trying to get me to establish, and how they've done so with their solution. In particular, what does $||x||=||y||\implies f(x)=f(y)$ establish? How do I/can I even interpret this intuitively? How does the "smooth curve" relate to the plan of attack/solution?

Answer (score 1):

Pick two points $x$ and $y$ of the same magnitude, say, $r$.  Then both $x$ and $y$ live on the sphere of radius $r$.  Now draw a little smooth curve $\gamma$ on this sphere that runs from $x$ to $y$, so $\gamma(a)=x$ and $\gamma(b)=y$.  Define $h: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ as they do, then use the chain rule and the assumptions on $f$ to deduce
$$
h'(t) = g(\gamma(t))(\gamma(t) \cdot \gamma'(t)).
$$
Since $\gamma$ lives on a sphere of constant radius [see note below], $\gamma(t) \cdot \gamma'(t)=0$, so $h'(t)=0$.  Thus $h$ is constant, so $h(a)=h(b)$.  But this says that
$$
f(\gamma(a))=f(\gamma(b)),
$$
i.e. that $f(x)=f(y)$.  By using the smooth curve $\gamma$, we are allowed to take this multivariable problem about $f$ and reduce it to the single-variable problem about $h$.  There we can use "ordinary" calculus and deduce that $h$ is constant from $h'=0$.

**Note:**  this part might be the only subtle bit of this.  It is a standard result in most textbooks that if $\gamma(t)$ has constant length then $\gamma(t) \cdot \gamma'(t)=0$ for all $t$.  To see this, apply the product rule to $\frac{d}{dt} (\gamma(t) \cdot \gamma(t))$.

Comment: Is $\gamma (t) \cdot \gamma '(t)=0$ denoting the dot product, or just a regular product? How is a dot product between two non-vectors (curves/functions in this case?) even defined?

Comment: If it's the dot product, how do you apply the chain rule (or any regular differentiation rules) to the dot product?

Comment: Can I also geometrically visualise how the "constant" curve $h(t)$ looks? Else, what is meant by $h$ being constant? What would it look like if it were non-constant?

Comment: For each $t$, $\gamma(t)$ is a vector of 3 components, and so is $\gamma'(t)$, so the dot product makes perfect sense.

Comment: How did you apply the chain rule to take this derative here? 
$ℎ′()=(())(()⋅′())$

Shouldn't it be $\gamma (t) f'(\gamma (t))$ from the product rule? How are you getting the dot product and the gradient vector? (btw, we've only covered derivatives of functions of the type $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in class)

Comment: It's the multivariable chain rule [or the chain rule for vector valued functions], which your instructor is clearly assuming that you know.  Whether or not that's a fair assumption, I cannot say.